# How to split a text field in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

My app contain a Registration Page. I have few text boxes, in that I want to split a text box into two, is that possible in iOS.
I have given the screen shot of it
[image]
Here, in this screenshot I want to split any one text box horizontally, both should do there own activities, each shouldn't be dependant on each other.

Comment: May be you need create few field for splitting?

Comment: Can you show info that you want see in your fields?

Comment: I couldn't understand what U r saying

Comment: The above screen shot is a sample, I wanted to split any one text field, one for entering time and other for entering money

Comment: In this scenario you have to create designs as per your requirement.Because you can not split textView or textField in iOS.You have to take two textFields and have to arrange it as per designs.

Comment: k, cant we customize a text field

Comment: Exactactly. It is called as customisation.You have to take two different textFields.and by giving tags you can identify textFields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't split one text field. If you really wanna it then you need to make two text filed horizontally and then make dependent each other.

Comment: k, cant we customize a text field

Comment: You can customize text field but in this case according to me use two test field horizontally and then made dependent each other. That will be better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't split one `UITextField` into two different parts but you can use two different `UITextFields`. Which is what I would advice for you to do, based on what you have said this should be what you are doing. There is no reason for you to not use two different `UITextFields`.

If this is your design to use one `UITextField` (Which doesn't make sense) I would revisit your design, but for what advantage splitting one `UITextField` into two different parts over using two different `UITextFields` I don't know.